# Combine multiple files into single file, append portion of each file name

Tags: text-processing, cat

I have a few hundred files that each contain a single numeric entry (ex: `5243564`).  Each file name has an identifier (FT, FM, FA, etc) and a date (ex: `FT.20180315.txt`).

I would like to combine unique identifier files and their number entry into a single file AND bring the date with it.  So a single FT file would look like:

```
20180315 5243564
20180316 1234566
```

etc

This would do it: `cat *FT* > FT.txt` .

But that won't bring each files' date with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `awk` one-liner should get the job done.

```
awk '{ printf("%s %s\n", substr(FILENAME, 4, 8), $0); }' FT.*.txt > FT.txt
```

I tested it on the examples you provided. Adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script, that would do what you need.  It is minimalistic, but shows the basic steps.  Let's assume this script is called: `combine.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

#Add logic for better parsing of args.
IDENT=$1
SEARCHDIR=$2

# For each file in the Search Directory
# that starts with the Unique Identifier...
for f in "$SEARCHDIR/$IDENT"*; do

   datestr=$(echo "$f" | cut -d '.' -f2)
   value=$(cat "$f")
   echo "$datestr $value"
done
```

Then you could simply do:

```
$> combine.sh FT /path/to/my/datadir > FT.txt
```

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Quote your variables: `echo "$f"`, `cat "$f"` -- actually `value=$(<"$f")` is a bash builtin for `$(cat "$f")`

Comment: @don_crissti - creates a for loop and assigns each filename in the output of `ls` to the variable `f`.

Comment: @glennjackman - Good point about the variable quoting - thanks!  I prefer to keep 'cat' command, as it's a little more readable.

Comment: @don_crissti - no reason; that works too and is more readable.  glennjackman made the edit in the solution above.

Comment: It's not only "more readable" it's also bullet proof. Imagine you had to loop over file names containing blanks...